# What is the purpose of this err function "next(err, err || doc._id)"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, express, backend

I am trying to understand what happens in the following function:

```
   next(err, err || doc._id)
```

I did some research into this but I am unable to find any documentation that explains the `next` function. Would someone explain its purpose?

```
function createQuestions(storyPrettyId, questions, author, callback) {
    async.map(
        questions,
        function(question, next) {
            QuestionMongoModel.create({
                storyPrettyId: storyPrettyId,
                title: question.title,
                answers: question.answers,
                author: author
            }, function(err, doc) {
                next(err, err || doc._id)
            })
        }, 
        callback
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank Ram, this was my first post to the site. i appreciate you showing my how its done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the documentation for [`async.map()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#map):

> **Arguments**
>
> - `arr` - An array to iterate over.
> - `iterator(item, callback)` - A function to apply to each item in `arr`. The iterator is passed a `callback(err, transformed)` which must be called once it has completed with an error (which can be `null`) and a transformed item.
> - `callback(err, results)` - *Optional* A callback which is called when all `iterator` functions have finished, or an error occurs. Results is an array of the transformed items from the `arr`.

The `next` is simply the `callback` parameter of the `iterator()` function that you're passing in to `async.map()`.